# Mysql application logging. Limit the number of rows logged by deleting the old logs

Tags: mysql, sql, logging, triggers

I have a log table in my Mysql database to log the events happening in my application. I want to limit the maximum number of rows in that table by deleting the old events(rows). Before deleting I want to save(backup) the old data which is going to remove to an external file. I want to run this trigger or event or whatever used to do this every 5 days or so automatically.

Comment: Welcome on Stackoverflow, stackoverflow isn't a free coding service but a question and answer website.. Stackoverflow expects you to atleast have done some [reseach/programming attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) yourself.. This question sounds like a plain hard ***"can somebody program it for free for me"*** request which is not how it works around here.. We are here to help you with programming problems where your are stuck but  yea without code we can't help

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” type of question and these are difficult to answer concisely, which makes them off-topic on Stack Overflow. If you can, make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete or broken, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. If you really don't know where to start and need guidance or support consider mentoring and coaching services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;


delimiter | 
CREATE event cleaner ON schedule every 7 day enable do 
BEGIN 
DECLARE maxtime TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE logCount integer;
SET maxtime = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval 180 day;
SET logCount = (Select count(*) from eventlogs);
DELETE FROM  eventlogs WHERE  eventlogs.TimeStamp < maxtime AND logCount > 1000 ; END 
| delimiter ;
```